# How to avoid bloating transactionlogs while creating an index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, transaction-log

Does anyone know to avoid bloating transactionlogs while creating an index?

My problem:
I have a script that creates a lot of Indexes. While running this script, my transactionlog doesn't stop growing. Is there a way, how to reduce logging while creating an index?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

if recovery model of your database is **full**, you can temporary switch your database to **bulk-logged recovery model**

If the database is set to the simple or **bulk-logged recovery model**, some index DDL operations (including CREATE INDEX) are minimally logged whether the operation is executed offline or online.

here is the list of such operations that can be minimally logged: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx